# Hello World causes Iphone 5s to freeze

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, iphone-5

I recently began going through the official Apple documentation and tutorials to learn iPhone development. I got my Iphone 5s a couple of days ago, but the sample ToDo list app that I'm making causes the device to lock up randomly when I try to test on the device. For example, I if I make a chance to the code and build/run it on the device, it will work. However, as I keep updating the code and testing it, eventually it will just open up my app on the device as a complete black screen, and freezes. The home button then no longer works, no touch events work, the only think I can do is to hold Home+lock button until the device shuts down.

This cannot be normal, can it? I mean, its just a basic app, what could be causing it?

Attached is the error that shows in xcode, and also a screenshot of the Iphone when it its frozen. Surprisingly, I was able to use the screenshot functionality on the phone... :/
[image: Xcode with an error when trying to run the app again, after the previous attempt has frozen the device.]
[image: Iphone with App all black and the device being frozen]

Comment: The issue is not related to your provisioning profile. It is code related. Please post the codes that you are using. The consul output says that the task is section of your code is not getting fired. Post your code so we can help you.

Comment: I can't attach a whole xcode project, which file should I post?

Comment: The section in .m file where the task task for the to do is being created. Also just post the link where this tutorial is, so I can build a sample and see where the issue is.

Comment: Tutorial is located: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/FirstTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH3-SW1)

Comment: Ok thanks for the link man. I'll build a proto type and see where the issue is. It's a bit late in my time zone so give me till tomorrow and I'll post what I can find man. Is that cool.? And also you can mail me your project, here is my email .. amp@xcodemonkey.com.. I'll look at it and will post my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are using a distribution provisioning profile/certificate to sign the app. If you plan to debug the app on the device (use breakpoints etc.), you should sign it with a development provisioning profile.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what I need to do? I messed around with the provisioning profiles to see if it will fix (i.e. I revoked certificate re-requested one, etc), but I still have the issue... :/

Comment: I also find it strange that its not very consistent, shouldn't it fail every single time if the app is not signed properly?

Comment: If you sign it with a distribution profile, you can build and install on any device- but you can not debug and run the app. You can go to your Project Target-> Build Settings-> Code Signing Identity/ Provisioning Profile section to check whether you have a dev/distribution prov profile/certificate. If the certificate is a dev vert, it will read as "iPhone Developer:<dev name>". If it's a distribution one, it will read as "iPhone Distribution: <dev name>".

Comment: ..and if you are sure that you are signing with dev profile/cert, please try what Tha has suggested below.

Comment: It's been set to Developer. I switched to "Distribution" to see if it will make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It only happens sometimes, so it's not provisioning related.

It causes a message to popup in XCode itself, so it's not code related.

I had the same problems before (not that often really...). What I did was

1. Restart the device
2. Remove the app from the device
3. Clear the project builds (CMD SHIFT K)
4. Restart XCode.
5. Build & Run again

I actually haven't seen this for a while. I always thought that they fixed the bug. Hope this helps!